# IP masquerade switch automatically between uplinks

Tags: iptables, failover

Running Debian 10 with two Internet connections.

The primary connection goes down and comes back periodically.

When `wlan0` goes down how can I get `enp0s6f1u2` to take over?
The Internet continues to work on the local box, but not for other devices on the network because `wlan0` is hard-coded into my `iptables` script.

How do I say in `iptables`: *output masquerade to whatever interface the default route is on*?

**`/etc/network/interfaces`**

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp0s10 inet manual


### WiFi for access point

allow-hotplug wlx00e032800384
iface wlx00e032800384 inet manual
        pre-up ip link set dev wlx00e032800384 address 02:e0:32:80:03:80


### Bridge: internal network

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
#       bridge_ports enp0s10 wlx00e032800384
        bridge_ports enp0s10 ap_wep ap_open
        address 192.168.1.31
        netmask 255.255.255.0


### WiFi to Internet: physical plus virtual for each network defined in wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
        wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
#        wpa-ssid RWB
#        wpa-psk MYWIFI3518

allow-hotplug RWB
iface RWB inet dhcp
        metric 1


### 4G to Internet (failover)

auto enp0s6f1u2
allow-hotplug enp0s6f1u2
iface enp0s6f1u2 inet dhcp
        metric 9999
```

**`iptables` script**

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X

# Squid transparent proxy for HTTP (not HTTPS)

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.31:3128
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128

# IP masquerade

iptables -A FORWARD -o wlan0 -i br0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE

# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

**Some `ip route`**

When both interfaces are up:

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.43.40 dev wlan0 metric 1
default via 192.168.42.129 dev enp0s6f1u2 metric 9999
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.31
192.168.42.0/24 dev enp0s6f1u2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.221
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.7
```

When `wlan0` has gone down:

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.42.129 dev enp0s6f1u2 metric 9999
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.31
192.168.42.0/24 dev enp0s6f1u2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.221
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I say in iptables: output masquerade to whatever interface the default route is on?

That happens by default – iptables does not decide the output interface in the first place. What your rule actually says is the opposite: "**if** the output interface is wlan0, then masquerade the packet". (This is in fact why the chain is named *post*routing.)

So you can simply two iptables rules, each matching one of the interfaces, and both applying the SNAT (masquerading). Alternatively, you can have a rule that matches by destination address and doesn't care about the interface (e.g. `! -s 192.168.0.0/16` to masquerade everything that isn't being sent to the LAN, regardless of interface).

(Same goes for your "FORWARD" rules – you can just have two of them, accepting traffic from all necessary interfaces.)

Comment: You're right: simply adding `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s6f1u2 -j MASQUERADE` has made it work. Thank you :D